# how to get the size of message queue from akka actor?

Tags: java, akka

There are Akka (Java API) actors (UntypeActor) and messages in the application.
According to API contract in case a few messages are addressed to the same actor, they are queued and processed with one-by-one.

I'd like to handle messages in the actor depending on queue size. Basically: is there at least one more message queued at the moment current one is handled in Actor.onReceive()? What is the Akka way to archive this?

Comment: Just remember that you're in the situation where a message can be added the nanosecond after your call to getMailboxSize()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From within the UntypedActor you do:

getContext().getMailboxSize();

Comment: No longer there in akka 2 http://letitcrash.com/post/17707262394/why-no-mailboxsize-in-akka-2

Comment: From the article: _In case you cannot do without, it is quite easy to write your own mailbox implementation, building on the traits in the akka.dispatch package and inserting book-keeping code into enqueue() and dequeue(). Then you could either use down-casting (evil) or keep track of your mailboxes in an akka.actor.Extension (recommended) to access the stats from within your actor and do whatever is necessary._