# how to check size of stash in akka actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-actor

I have implemented stashing in the actor, using the stash method in Akka actor, but now need to view its size ( i.e no of messages in stash). Is there any way to do so?

Below are the method and its documentation -

```
/**
   *  Adds the current message (the message that the actor received last) to the
   *  actor's stash.
   *
   *  @throws StashOverflowException in case of a stash capacity violation
   *  @throws IllegalStateException  if the same message is stashed more than once
   */
  def stash(): Unit = {
    val currMsg = actorCell.currentMessage
    if (theStash.nonEmpty && (currMsg eq theStash.last))
      throw new IllegalStateException(s"Can't stash the same message $currMsg more than once")
    if (capacity <= 0 || theStash.size < capacity) theStash :+= currMsg
    else throw new StashOverflowException(
      s"Couldn't enqueue message ${currMsg.message.getClass.getName} from ${currMsg.sender} to stash of $self")
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest that you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343731/how-to-get-the-size-of-message-queue-from-akka-actor).

Comment: Why can't you just count the number of times you call `stash` and clear the count on `unstashAll`?

Answer (score 0):

In akka, Stash is internally implemented as StashBuffer. A StashBuffer is a non thread safe mutable message buffer that can be used to buffer messages inside actors and then unstash them. The buffer can hold at most the given capacity number of messages.

The StashBuffer is a trait

```
trait StashBuffer[T] extends AnyRef
```

which contains the size method

```
abstract def size: Int
```

which denotes 
the number the number of elements in the message buffer. Please refer https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl/StashBuffer.html

Comment: That reference is about Akka Typed, and I don't think this question is about that version of Akka.